# Serial port sometimes takes (exactly) 30 seconds to Open or Close, only connects once without manual RTS control

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm having a very peculiar issue with the serial port class in C# (using .NET 4.5 as a target).  Our application needs the ability to switch between (close then open another) serial COM ports which are all USB 1.1 virtual COM port devices.  The problem I'm having has two symptoms that may be related.  First, we can only connect to our device after having already read from it using another terminal emulator or similar application and even then only once.  After one successful connection all other attempts after closing and re-opening the port will never receive data (DataReceivedEvent never fires).  The only workaround I have found to this is to manually drive the RTS signal as shown below (even though every other serial library or emulation program requires no handshaking to talk to this device, including TerraTerm, Java, and PySerial).

Second, even then, while the port may be freely opened and closed successful, occasionally (1/30 ish) the Open() or Close() functions take precisely 30 seconds to finish (30008 ms measured via a diagnostic Stopwatch) where it would normally take a mere 5-8 ms.  There seems to be no explanation for this.  Any thoughts?

Measures already used to try eliminating or mitigating the problem:

- Attempts to Open or Close the port are executed as separate tasks in the thread pool so that they can be terminated or aborted cleanly after a specified period of time if unsuccessful (I use 60 seconds for this value in testing)
- I've added various time delays both short (100 ms) and extreme (5000 ms) in every conceivable place with no effect (between port close and reopen, between open and close, and between open/close and RTS true/false
- Double triple and quadruple checked the designed port parameters for our USB serial device
- I've looked at [this article](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport#comment-393%20this%20article) by bvoigt and [this article](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html) by Zach Saw which both seem to suggest that there are deeply rooted issues with .NET SerialPort class.  This has left me with the impression that a third party library might be the best option (there are some good candidates on NuGet).  Ultimately this will be used as the serial port within a WPF application.
- Before anyone asks, **no**, simply opening the port and leaving it open is not an option in our application and, frankly, this is something that works seamlessly 100% of the time with the same device from the same hosts with the same driver in other languages' standard serial implementations (see above).

Please see the simple exemplary application below which I have been using to successfully reproduce this problem.  Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!!!

**SerialTestApplication.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerialTestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private SerialPort S = new SerialPort();
        private bool S_active = false;

        private int succeed = 0;
        private int fail = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program P = new Program();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var test_timer = new Stopwatch();
            test_timer.Start();

            for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
            {
                P.ConnectSerial(P);
                P.CloseSerial(P);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("EXIT");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private bool ConnectSerial(Program P)
        {
            if (S.IsOpen)
            {
                fail++;

                Console.WriteLine("PORT NOT CLOSED YET");
                return false;
            }

            // Setup The Serial COMM Port
            S.PortName = "COM1";
            S.BaudRate = 115200;
            S.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            S.Parity = Parity.None;
            S.DataBits = 8;
            S.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            // Write Properties
            S.WriteBufferSize = 2048;
            S.WriteTimeout = 500;

            // Read Properties
            S.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
            S.ReadBufferSize = 2048;
            S.ReadTimeout = 500;

            try
            {
                S_active = false;

                if (!P.OpenSerial(P))
                {
                    fail++;
                    return false;
                }

                var connection_timer = new Stopwatch();
                connection_timer.Start();

                while (S.IsOpen && !S_active)
                {
                    if (connection_timer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1000)
                    {
                        fail++;

                        CloseSerial(this);

                        Console.WriteLine("Succeed/Fail: " + succeed + " " + fail);
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                succeed++;
                Console.WriteLine("Succeed/Fail: " + succeed + " " + fail);
                Console.WriteLine(S.BytesToWrite + " " + S.BytesToRead);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void Receive(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (S.IsOpen)
            {
                S_active = true;
                S.ReadExisting();
            }
        }

        private bool OpenSerial(Program P)
        {
            Task OpenAttempt = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (S.IsOpen)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PORT STILL OPEN!");
                        return;
                    }

                    S.Open();
                    S.DiscardInBuffer();
                    S.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Receive);
                    S.RtsEnable = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            });

            var open_timer = new Stopwatch();
            open_timer.Start();

            OpenAttempt.Wait(60000);

            Console.WriteLine("Opened In: " + open_timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            return S.IsOpen;
        }

        private void CloseSerial(Program P)
        {
            Task CloseAttempt = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    S.RtsEnable = false;
                    S.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            });

            var close_timer = new Stopwatch();
            close_timer.Start();

            CloseAttempt.Wait(60000);

            Console.WriteLine("Closed In: " + close_timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I've found one issue with this but unfortunately it doesn't solve the core "takes 30 seconds to finish the Open() or Close() method" problem.  The way I am recycling (closing and reopening) the SerialPort object in this test application ***adds a new DataReceived event handler every time the port is reopened***.  Basically after closing/opening the port 10 times there will be ten DataReceived handlers associated with the object.  To correct that I'm now letting Close() Dispose() the SerialPort object then setting the reference to null and creating a completely new instance of SerialPort on the next open.  That seems to ensure that the serial port is properly released so long as the USB cable is not physically pulled out of the computer.

Comment: There's no need to use a task just to close a serial port.

Comment: @MickyD Using a separate thread was recommended by some MSDN articles as a way of preventing the Close() function from being able to hang the application for an indeterminate amount of time.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce8ce1a3-64ed-4f26-b9ad-e2ff1d3be0a5/serial-port-hangs-whilst-closing?forum=Vsexpressvcs.  That said I **completely** agree with you, the fact that such a thing is even _possibly_ needed seems insane.

Comment: Ah ok.  You could try enabling hardware DTR-DSR flow control.  Normally if you drop DTR it kills the dataset

Comment: @MickyD Unfortunately I don't think I can connect successfully at all when applying that hardware control mode.  Are you saying that when writing DTR false on the SerialPort object it clears out the objects internal read/write buffers?  I'll take a look at whether there's still data in those two buffers when the 30 second open issue happens and let you know.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide a brief statement at the top of your question? I've got tons of C#/embedded/serial experience, may be able to help out here.

Comment: Hey @Snoopy, thanks for your comment.  Ultimately, making an application in which you can select ports from a menu and click a connect toggle button.  Clicking the toggle again will disconnect.  I provided the example I did here to remove the UI from the question entirely.  What we're experiencing is, sometimes (~1/100 times) the call to Open() takes 30 seconds to complete.  The same can happen for Close(). We can't take the more typical approach of "open a port and never close it" because users may want to switch between connecting to one port and another without re-opening the application.

Comment: @LiquidPlasmas It seems like your real problem might almost be... You're actually failing to connect to your device 30 times and just sleeping 1s for each time, maybe? It's hard to say, we'd almost need to see what the connection command/response looks like.

Comment: @LiquidPlasmas Here's something to try... Remove any kind of timing/time-out mechanisms that you have from the entire program. Just sit on the port and keep reading until you get the "I'm connected!" state from your device. See how long it takes in that situation... Ask yourself, is it still taking 30 seconds, or did the problem go away? My bet is that your problem goes away.